# How to play song with image using both image path and audio path in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, avaudioplayer

I am new to I phone programming.Images and audios i have store in Private document folder,In database i have created Id,name,image path,audio path i have stored all those think in database.when iam retrieve data from database its show in console like this.

1|Picture0001|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Images/Picture0001.jpg|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Audios/song.mp3

2|Picture0002|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Images/Picture0002.jpg|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Audios/song1.mp3

Now i got path like this in console using this i want to display only image in table view if click that image means it have to play song in next view.Till now what i did i am able  to display path in table view instead of path,i want to display image if click on that image i want to play song.This think how to do any idea.Is it possible to play song Using path image path and audio path.

Answer (score 1):

Declare two **NSMutableArray** properties (use a class instead of two NSMutableArray)

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *imageCollection;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *songCollection;
```

**Allocate them in `viewDidLoad`**

```
self.imageCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.songCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**Add objects**

```
  [self.imageCollection addObject:@"Picture0001"];
  [self.imageCollection addObject:@"Picture0002"];

  [self.songCollection addObject:@"/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Images/Picture0001.jpg|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Audios/song.mp3"];
  [self.songCollection addObject:@"/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Images/Picture0002.jpg|/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7CA908BE-79DC-44EE-BEA9-A4DBF1736062/Documents/Tauky/Audios/song1.mp3"];
```

**[Implement UITableView](http://codingcluster.blogspot.in/2012/02/add-image-to-uitableviewcell-without.html)**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];        
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];


    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    NSString *imageName = [self.imageCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Implement UitableView **didSelectRowAtIndexPath*** delegate*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *songURL = [self.songCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //play song here or pass the songURL to another controller and play it in view didload

}
```

Comment: hi in tableview image is not displaying just text is displaying and if click on cell its black, song is not playing.in place of [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; i have to given imagecollection